# xAxis startOnTick and endOnTick options ignored on boxplots

Tags: highcharts

It seems that the options `startOnTick`, and `endOnTick` have no effect on a boxplot. Is there anyway to align the outermost ticks to the graph edge with a boxplot?

```
xAxis: {
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true,
  min: -1,
  max: 6,
},
```

I have tried adding most combinations of minPadding/maxPadding, tickmarkPlacement: between/on, and manually setting ticks with tickPositioner without any luck. The only workaround I have is to shrink min/max so the padding fixes itself. I would prefer a better solution, because this workaround becomes very ugly for dynamic data.

Here is the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zK4JV/) demonstrating the problem and [another](http://jsfiddle.net/DX7P7/) with the workaround. Again, is there any way to align the outermost ticks to the graph edge with a boxplot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking into this led me to these comments buried in [parts/Axis.js](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/88c0013b0d8a1447fe477af151e64002f59f0ecf/js/parts/Axis.js#L2858).

```
                if (!axis.single) {
                    // minPointOffset is the value padding to the left of
                    // the axis in order to make room for points with a
                    // pointRange, typically columns. When the
                    // pointPlacement option is 'between' or 'on', this
                    // padding does not apply.
                    minPointOffset = Math.max(
                        minPointOffset,
                        isString(pointPlacement) ? 0 : seriesPointRange / 2
                    );

                    // Determine the total padding needed to the length of
                    // the axis to make room for the pointRange. If the
                    // series' pointPlacement is 'on', no padding is added.
                    pointRangePadding = Math.max(
                        pointRangePadding,
                        pointPlacement === 'on' ? 0 : seriesPointRange
                    );
                }
```

The issue is caused by the point padding and probably occurs on any column style plot. The padding will be ignored if `pointPlacement` is set to `'on'` or `'between'` on the series.

```
series: {
  type: 'boxplot',
  pointPlacement: 'on',
  data: ...
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UyStL/) is the working fiddle.